# Where does this directory in the error message point to?

Tags: c++, xcode, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I was running a program in Xcode, however the output generated is

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /fserver/mo/engine_build/BUILD_mac_64/climp/LIBS/nag_lm/libnagc_nag.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/William/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Regression_Function-cmkvscbmyfohphbgblelwgtabfup/Build/Products/Debug/Regression Function Reason: image not found

I checked but there is no directory called `/fserver` under root. What does the error message mean and where is the path `/fserver/mo/engine_build/BUILD_mac_64/climp/LIBS/nag_lm/libnagc_nag.dylib`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in terms of MacOS/iOS/etc, but for me it seems like a path somewhere on Apple's build cluster. Libraries generated by C-family tools often come with some not-yet-stripped debug information that allows you to see 'what line of code' has crashed in which file, and then they contain the paths exactly from the machine the library was built on. Although they make sense only there, some sub-path of that may make sense to you, provided that you have some grasp on the related projects. In this example, I'd guess that

```
climp/LIBS/nag_lm/libnagc_nag.dylib
```

or

```
LIBS/nag_lm/libnagc_nag.dylib
```

is the actual project-wise **relative path** that may make some sense. The rest seems like target-specific prefix generated by build system. On the other hand, what this path is relative to, is quite a hard question..